# Perturbation theory for almost degenerate matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, approximation, perturbation-theory

I have a nearly degenerate matrix $A$ and a perturbation $\epsilon B$, where $\epsilon$ is a small positive number. I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, but as I said, some of the eigenvalues of $A$ can be very close to each other.

I need to find an approximate analytical expression for the eigenvalues of $A + \epsilon B$. Conventional perturbation theory does not work, because of the small denominators. Moreover, I think degenerate perturabtion theory does not apply because the matrix $A$ is not really degenerate (it almost is).

Is there a theory that I can apply in this case?

Comment: A certain similarity with the question you have asked an hour ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2439354).

Comment: @JeanMarie It's part of the same problem :P But they are different questions, though.

Comment: You may consider perturbation analysis for block Schur decomposition with blocks containing close eigenvalues.

Comment: @PawelKowal Can you point me to some references?

Comment: @becko General overview can be found in Daniel Kressner, Numerical Methods for General and Structured Eigenvalue Problems. 
Lecture Notes in Computational Science and Engineering 46, Springer 2005. 

Dieci, Luca, and Timo Eirola. "On smooth decompositions of matrices." 
SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications 20.3 (1999): 800-819 contains many useful results.